# How to animate feTurbulence to appear continuous

Tags: html, svg-filters, svg-animate

The feTurbulence filter is used to create clouds. By animating frequency value, generated clouds are zoomed in or out. I want them to slide from right to left.
I've made so far:

```html
<svg height="0" width="0" style=";position:absolute;margin-left: -100%;">
 <defs>
  <filter id="imagenconturbulencias" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
   <feTurbulence result="cloud" baseFrequency=".2" seed="22" stitchTiles="nostitch" type="fractalNoise" numOctaves="3">
   <animate
    attributeName="baseFrequency"
    calcMode="spline"
    dur="5s"
    values=".2;.1;"
    repeatCount="indefinite"
   />
   </feTurbulence>
   <feComposite operator="in" in="cloud" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
  </filter>
 </defs>
 <g stroke="none" stroke-width="4" id="rlog" fill="#eee"><path d="M34.2,13.9v19.5h-7.3V13.9H34.2z M30.5,5.2c1,0,1.8,0.3,2.6,1s1.1,1.5,1.1,2.5c0,1-0.3,1.8-1,2.5s-1.6,1-2.6,1c-1.1,0-1.9-0.3-2.6-1s-1-1.5-1-2.5c0-1,0.4-1.8,1.1-2.5S29.5,5.2,30.5,5.2z"/></g>
</svg>

<div id="a">
 <svg viewBox="0 0 230 280">
  <use filter="url(#imagenconturbulencias)" xlink:href="#rlog"></use>
 </svg>
</div>
```

If you look closely, after 5 seconds animation repeats itself, as should! but it does not look so pretty.

I know this filter is used to create realistic, cloud-like structures. How do we go about moving these clouds continuously ?

[feTurbulence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feTurbulence) filter takes in parameters like randomSeed numberOfOctaves and baseFrequency.

In given example I've animated value of base frequency. Since there is no more attributes to animate.

**How to make this animation to appear continuous?** Do we use perlin noise generator combined with matrix and displacement maps on this turbulence generated thing and animate all together somehow? (just brainstorming..)

Any help, Ideas, approaches, snippets, sincerely appreciated.

---

this could be black&white for simplicity, but cloud animation still is not continious. [Bonus snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/v3wpjmrs/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not animate the base frequency. For a smooth effect use a 360 hueRotate and a colorMatrix (since hueRotate cycles back to the original value).

```html
<svg x="0px" y="0px" width="800px" height="500px" viewbox="0 0 800 500">

    <script type="text/ecmascript" xlink:href="http://www.codedread.com/lib/smil.user.js"/>

  <defs>
<filter id="heavycloud" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" x="0%" y="0%" height="100%" width="100%">
  <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" result="cloudbase" baseFrequency=".0025" numOctaves="5" seed="24"/>

    <feColorMatrix in="cloudbase" type="hueRotate" values="0" result="cloud">
    <animate attributeName="values" from="0" to="360" dur="20s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </feColorMatrix>


  <feColorMatrix in="cloud" result="wispy" type="matrix" 
                               values="4 0 0 0 -1
                                       4 0 0 0 -1
                                       4 0 0 0 -1
                                       1 0 0 0 0   
                                       "/>

  <feFlood flood-color="#113388" result="blue"/>

  <feBlend mode="screen" in2="blue" in="wispy"/>

  <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="4"/>

  <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic"/>

</filter>
  </defs>
  <text x="30" y="380" filter="url(#heavycloud)" font-size="400" font-family="arial" stroke-color="blue" font-weight="bold" kerning="-75" font-stretch="condensed">SVG!</text>


</svg>
```

Comment: This is an answer. Sorry for late approval, I missed notification.. found this question searching for answers. Ironic, this is my question.