# Use feTurbulence SVG tag to mimc Musgrave texture animation

Tags: animation, svg, noise

I'm trying to make a procedural animated background for a website.  I want to combine the colorful lines of a basic feTurbulence SVG:
[image]

And the motion of a musgrave texture from Blender:

[image]

I had to compress the gif considerably for it to upload.

I tried reading [another stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29966256/how-to-animate-feturbulence-to-appear-continuous) and using the  tag, but it yielded no satisfying results.  I was able to use a hue rotate matrix to change the colors at least, but the bright white lines don't move.  What advice can you guys offer?

Comment: The effect seems to be achieved by showing the intersection of a **three-dimensional** Perlin noise field with the surface of a cube, and then changing the scale at which the field is shown. This way, you always see differently positioned intersections of the field with the plane. This is impossible to achieve with the feTurbulence filter primitive, as its Perlin noise field is only **two-dimensional**. All you could do with this is intersecting its plane with a line and move the field across that line. But then the effect could be only be seen in **one** dimension...